Troubleshooting Local Deployment Errors with DFINITY’s dfx
I have been having this issue and stuck on this for quite a while now. After you run dfx start, it fails to deploy the project locally and not sure what is resulting into failing to build the frontend. Checked up all dependencies, file pathways which are all up to date. Running out of ideas on solving this at this point. The error goes like this:
Deploying all canisters.
Creating canisters...
Creating canister dkeeper_backend...
Creating a wallet canister on the local network.
The wallet canister on the "local" network for user "MyNewIdentity" is "bnz7o-iuaaa-aaaaa-qaaaa-cai"
dkeeper_backend canister created with canister id: bkyz2-fmaaa-aaaaa-qaaaq-cai
Creating canister dkeeper_frontend...
dkeeper_frontend canister created with canister id: bd3sg-teaaa-aaaaa-qaaba-cai
Creating canister internet_identity...
internet_identity canister created with canister id: be2us-64aaa-aaaaa-qaabq-cai
Building canisters...
Building frontend...
Error: Failed while trying to deploy canisters.
Caused by: Failed to build all canisters.
Caused by: Failed while trying to build all canisters.
Caused by: The post-build step failed for canister 'bd3sg-teaaa-aaaaa-qaaba-cai' (dkeeper_frontend)
Caused by: Failed to build frontend for network 'local'.
Caused by: The command 'cd "/Users/raiasim93/dfinity-ic-projects/dkeeper" && CANISTER_CANDID_PATH="/Users/raiasim93/dfinity-ic-projects/dkeeper/.dfx/local/canisters/dkeeper_frontend/assetstorage.did" CANISTER_CANDID_PATH_DKEEPER_BACKEND="/Users/raiasim93/dfinity-ic-projects/dkeeper/.dfx/local/canisters/dkeeper_backend/dkeeper_backend.did" CANISTER_ID="bd3sg-teaaa-aaaaa-qaaba-cai" CANISTER_ID_DKEEPER_BACKEND="bkyz2-fmaaa-aaaaa-qaaaq-cai" CANISTER_ID_DKEEPER_FRONTEND="bd3sg-teaaa-aaaaa-qaaba-cai" CANISTER_ID_INTERNET_IDENTITY="be2us-64aaa-aaaaa-qaabq-cai" DFX_NETWORK="local" DFX_VERSION="0.21.0" "npm" "run" "build" "--workspace" "dkeeper_frontend"' failed with exit status 'exit status: 1'.
Stdout:

Stderr:
npm error No workspaces found:
npm error   --workspace=dkeeper_frontend

Got nothing back from the ICP Developer Community, the MOD who was active did not have any experience with front end so putting this out for everyone to see. Checked the code several times, ran it across various sites yet nothing.
Error screenshot

My try is to run npm i under the root folder first, then dfx deploy went through without error.
